# Is it safe to initialize a class object within another class without using new?

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes A and B. I am declaring object of class A in B. And I am initializing the object in class B constructor. Is it a wrong way to do this? I mean, whether memory allocated to ojbA will always be available or it will be destroyed when the constructor of B completed. Also, this is just a sample example. You may suggest that I can initialize a=0, instead of defining a separate constructor. But lets say, its not allowed.

```
 class A{
     public:
            int x;
            A(){
               x=0;
            }
            A(int a){
                    x=a;
            }
};
class B{
     public:
           A objA;
           B(){
                    ojbA=A(3);
            }
};
```

Comment: Yes, though you would be better off using the initializer list for this purpose.

Comment: And perhaps `Second` isn't a good name for a constructor of a class named `B`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I renamed the class but forgot to rename the constructor.

Comment: You can still fix the error in your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the aggregate A inside B to initialize always to let say 3 its better to do this:

```
 class A{
     public:
            int x;
            A(){
               x=0;
            }
            A(int a){
                    x=a;
            }
};
class B{
     public:
           A objA;
           B() : objA(3)
           {

           }
};
```

If you do not have pointers and buffers in B you should not worry about memory allocations etc. Object objA will start to exist only when B start to exist, B* b = new B(), will allocate all the necessary memory. It is however better to initialize all aggregates like objA in this way rather than using assign operator.

Comment: Ok, but what problem can arise in using assignment operator ?

Comment: @user3747190 If you use your way, the object will first be constructed using the default constructor A() and then use assignment operator to assign a new value. That can have a performance penalty if the default constructor of A would do a lot of work. With the initializer list you only call the constructor and nothing else.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it's in fact a wrong way to use it.

The fact that you do this:

```
B(){
  ojbA=A(3);
}
```

Create an object A and affect the variable objA by using it's copy constructor, wich you haven't defined.

It would be better to do it like this:
B() : objA(3) {}

And if you don't understand how this sample of code work i invite you to look after initialization list (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: Most classes shouldn't need a manually defined copy constructor. While initialization lists are more appropriate, in this case it's not at all 'wrong'.

Comment: It's rather the copy assignement constructor, and not defining it doesn't mean it doesn't exist, and this code is in fact fine (though it could be better).

Comment: There is no copy construction being done in that statement whatsoever. its *assignment*.